# Trooper tattoos on other classes?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I read somewhere that if you get a cyborg species to lvl 50, that all the cybernetics will be available on other classes, is this true?

Also, is there a way to get the trooper tattoos on say a bounty hunter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; once you get any species to level 50, that species is available for use with any class at character creation time.

As for markings, hairstyles, etc. those do not get unlocked.  BioWare has been working on making some features available across species and adding new hairstyles, but these have to be bought from the Cartel Market.  I do not believe that those tattoos specifically have been made available.